# Starting WebSphere Message Queue manager from java

Tags: java, ibm-mq

Can we write a code in Java to start/stop a queue manager? I haven't come across any Java API which can be used for this.

Comment: Reading documentation often helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute `strmqm <qm name>` command from your Java program to start the queue manager.

**Example:**

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin\strmqm QM1");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Shashi, but I am not sure how to wrap this command in java.

Comment: Thanks so much Shashi for your response, I am able to start and stop using this. But would like to know how we can provide username and password for starting the queue manager. I had to run as an administrator to make this code work. Tried setting credentials using MQEnvironment, but it dosent work. Any idea on this?

Comment: Starting/Stopping is an administrative job, must be run under Administrative authority. No you can't use MQEnvironment to start/stop queue manager. The MQEnvironment is used by applications for setting connection information to connect to queue manager. PS: If you are satisfied with response above, do you mind accepting it as an answer?Thx

Comment: Thanks for your response Shashi. This definitely answers my question